# Activate a tab of another application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a running tabbed application and I would like to select and reload a particular tab of that application from another application. What methods/approaches would you please suggest me to do now ?

For example, I am interested in reloading a web tab control of opera browser, I am currently opening a page in tab 1 and I would like my program to select/focus on tab 2. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [SendMessage()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage) to do this. This is a Windows function that allows you to send messages to windows, and these windows do not have to belong to your application. In Windows applications can be identified by their Window Handle. You can use HWND_BROADCAST to hit all top-level windows like the Opera browser. Message are used to distinguish which action should take place. Some classic ones are WM_PAINT (paint the window) and WM_QUIT (terminate the app). You can use tools like [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242713%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to work out which messages need to be sent.

Recent versions of Windows have included more security around windows messages so you might hit some hurdles. If both applications are running in the same desktop session you should be OK.

Another approach that you might be interested in is Window Hooking. It is a more complex topic but there is a great library called [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) which will help you.